# pygame cant load image. Other solutions not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to load an image with this code:

```
img_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "\\assets\\ms_cell_normal.png"
img = pg.image.load(img_path)

game_display = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

while True:

    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit(0)

    game_display.blit(img, (50,50))
    game_display.flip()
```

Somehow, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/PythonProjects/MineSweeper/main.py", line 59, in <module>
    game_display.flip()
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'flip'
```

why ? I read everywhere that this is the way you load images ...

Answer (score 2):

`flip()` is not a method of [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). But there is [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

<s>`game_display.flip()`</s>

```py
pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Compared to that [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) is a mehtod of `pygame.Surface` and `game_display` is an instance of `pygame.Surface`:

```py
game_display.blit(img, (50,50))
```

Notice that you named the *Surface* associated with the window `game_display` when you created it (`game_display = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))`)

Comment: now I have AttributeError: module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'blit'

Comment: @derpascal I cry now. It is `pygame.display.flip()` but `game_display.blit(img, (50,50))`. [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) is a method of `pygame.Surface`

Comment: @derpascal I have a question to you. If there is a red and a green button and someone asks you to press the green button, what do you do? Do you press both buttons?